# Change a hash into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an Rails 4 application that collects attendance at church services. Some weeks there are two services and some weeks there is only one. I need to get the total attendance for each week and show it as a graph.

By calling:

```
Stat.calculate(:sum, :attendance, group: :date)
```

in the console I have been able to collect the data in a hash like this:

{Sun, 06 Jan 2013=>66, Sun, 13 Jan 2013=>65, Sun, 20 Jan 2013=>60, Sun, 27 Jan 2013=>67, Sun, 03 Feb 2013=>60, Sun, 10 Feb 2013=>76, Sun, 17 Feb 2013=>65, Sun, 24 Feb 2013=>52, Sun, 03 Mar 2013=>52, Sun, 10 Mar 2013=>45, Sun, 17 Mar 2013=>56, Sun, 24 Mar 2013=>134, Sun, 31 Mar 2013=>76, Sun, 07 Apr 2013=>88, Sun, 14 Apr 2013=>87, Sun, 28 Apr 2013=>93, Sun, 05 May 2013=>93, Sun, 12 May 2013=>95, Sun, 19 May 2013=>90, Sun, 26 May 2013=>87, Sun, 02 Jun 2013=>71, Sun, 09 Jun 2013=>86, Sun, 16 Jun 2013=>109, Sun, 23 Jun 2013=>80, Sun, 30 Jun 2013=>68, Sun, 07 Jul 2013=>75, Sun, 14 Jul 2013=>73}

But What I need for my chart is an array of hashes in the form of:

{date: "Sun, 23 Jun 2013", attendance: 80}, {date: "Sun, 30 Jun 2013", attendance: 68"}

So I am trying to figure out how to convert the first form into the second form.

I'm sure its something pretty easy, but my limited rails knowledge is hitting a wall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.collect{|key,value| {:date => key, :attendance => value} }
```

loop through and create a new hash where the original key becomes the value for date and the original value becomes the value for attendance.  These new hashes are collected into an array.

Comment: I agree. I used the first answer prior to seeing Shawn's response. I've refactored to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can think as below:

```
h = {"Sun, 06 Jan 2013"=>66, "Sun, 13 Jan 2013"=>65, "Sun, 20 Jan 2013"=>60 }
h.map{|k,v| Hash[:date,k,:attend,v]}
# => [{:date=>"Sun, 06 Jan 2013", :attend=>66},
#     {:date=>"Sun, 13 Jan 2013", :attend=>65},
#     {:date=>"Sun, 20 Jan 2013", :attend=>60}]
```

Comment: @NielsB. made it readble... :) Ready for all challenges.. :)))

Comment: That is better, but I still prefers Shawns answer because it reads well and only requires you to know the collect/map method. Your example also requires you to know the counter intuitive [] class method from the Hash class.

Comment: @NielsB. I have no issue... I liked my one, I use `Kernel#Hash` instead of `{}`.. simple.. :))) But thanks for throwing your comment.. :) I like feedbacks...